# A question about cubic equation.

Tags: polynomials, roots

I'd like to share my doubt on cubic equation.

Step 1: $ax^3+bx^2+cx+d=0$,

Step 2: We can substitute $x=y-\frac b {3a}$ to get $y^3+py+q=0$ where $p,q$ are something.

Step 3: By *[**Vieta's substitution**](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/VietasSubstitution.html)*, we substitute $z-\frac p {3z}=y$ and get $z^6+qz^3-\frac {p^3}{27}=0$

Step 4: $z^3=-\frac q 2\pm\sqrt{(\frac q 2)^2+(\frac p 3)^3}$

Step 5: Substitute $A=-\frac q 2+\sqrt{(\frac q 2)^2+(\frac p 3)^3},B=-\frac q 2-\sqrt{(\frac q 2)^2+(\frac p 3)^3}$, we get $z=\sqrt[3]A,\sqrt[3]A\omega,\sqrt[3]A\omega^2,\sqrt[3]B,\sqrt[3]B\omega$ or $\sqrt[3]B\omega^2$ where $\omega=\frac {\sqrt 3i-1}2$.

Step 6: $AB=-\frac {p^3}{27},y=z-\frac p {3z}$,therefore $y=z+\frac {\sqrt[3]{AB}} z$.

Here, I don't understand. Why needn't we consider $\sqrt[3]{AB}=\frac p 3\omega$ or $\frac p 3\omega^2$.

Thank you.

Comment: Probably because you've got many options for $z$, and taking a different value for $\root3\of{AB}$ probably just amounts to taking a different value for $z$.